# Does unordered map frees its memory after calling clear?

Tags: c++11

I know that unordered map removes the objects that were stored in it when doing clear() but does it also relinquishes the memory (back to OS) that it holds to create itself.

```
struct A{
   A(){std::cout << "constructor called\n";}

   ~A(){std::cout << "destructor called\n";}
};

// this will reserve size of 1000 buckets
std::unordered_map<int, A> my_map{1000};
     // now insert into the map
     my_map[1] = "asdf";
     my_map[2] = "asdff";
     ....
```

then I do `my_map.clear();` This will call destructor of A.

So my question is will the 1000 buckets that was reserved also be freed? I tried looking at the size() after doing clear it says zero, so is there something like capacity for unordered_map that is similar to vector that would let me view the reserved size?

Comment: There is no requirement in the C++ standard to do either (or to have an OS) so you need to specify your compiler and OS.  But the answer wil be "no" 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that unordered map removes the objects that were stored in it when doing clear() but does it also relinquishes the memory (back to OS) that it holds to create itself.

There is no guarantee (in particular because the C++11 specification does not know what an OS is), and in practice it often don't release the memory to the OS (that is, your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) might stay unchanged).

What happens is that (without specific `Allocator` argument to the [`std::map` template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), or to [`std::unordered_map` template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) the memory is `delete`-d (or `delete[]`-d). And if you really care a lot, implement your [own `Allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) andd pass it appropriately to your container templates. I'm not sure that is worth the trouble.

Usually `new` calls `malloc` & `delete` calls `free`. In that case in most (but not all) cases the memory is not released to the kernel (e.g. with [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) on Linux...) but just marked as re-usable by future calls to `new`.

Details are of course implementation specific. Many `free` (or `delete`) implementations would for example release with `munmap` a large enough block (of several megabytes or more). The exact threshold vary from one implementation to the next one.

Notice that if you use [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. a Linux system with GCC, GNU libc, ....), you could look into the source code of your C++ standard library (the code of `std::map`  and of `::operator delete` etc... inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and of your C standard library (the code of `free`) and find out by yourself these gory details.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to look into C++ standard library .. its gold mine there

Answer (score 2):

> will the 1000 buckets that was reserved also be freed?

This is not specified by the standard.

> is there something like capacity for unordered_map that is similar to vector that would let me view the reserved size?

A simple "capacity" value doesn't make sense for a hash map. Rehashing happens when [`load_factor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/load_factor) exceeds [`max_load_factor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_load_factor). You can check the number of buckets using [`bucket_count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_count).

Comment: bucket_count is what I was looking for .. thank you :)